# How to put text above dots indicator - Viewpager - KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, indicator

I'm using a library called [PageIndicatorView](https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView), which is a light library to indicate ViewPager's selected page with different animations and ability to customise it as you need. Till here everything is ok, until I started to realize that I need to do the following scenario to my "dots":

[image: a]

The dots are dynamic, and the number of them is conditioned by the number of images available on the viewpager. Can you tell how I can put these texts above my dots? Can you help me how to "fish", please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Either you can put that text in separate layout and handle the page change listener to update the UI or you can check this library - https://dubedout.eu/2016/11/13/viewpager-indicator-libraries-you-should-know/